# How to use RotateAround with Time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private float degrees = 90f;
```

&

```
transform.RotateAround(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f), new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f), degrees)
```

So I want to rotate my `gameObject` for 2 seconds from 0 degrees to 90 degrees. What should I do? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you want something to happen smooth over time in Unity you usually use [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

> The completion time in seconds since the last frame.

On this way you convert any "speed" parameter from "amount / frame" into a framerate-independent "amount / seconds".

Then as you want the rotation to take 2 seconds or in this case have a speed `45° / s` you simply multiply/devide by the according factor

```
transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, degrees / durationInSeconds * Time.deltaTime);
```

---

If you rather want to do the rotation about 90° for 2 seconds but than stop you should use a [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

```
StartCoroutine(Rotate(90, 2));

// flag to avoid concurrent routines
private bool isRotating;

private IEnumerator Rotate(float degrees, float duration)
{
    if(isRotating) yield break;
    isRotating = true;

    var startRotation = transform.rotation;
    var targetRotation = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, degrees);

    // Iterate for the given duration while keeping track of the current time progress
    for(var passedTime = 0f; passedTime < duration; passedTime += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        // this will always be a linear value between 0 and 1
        var lerpFactor = passedTime / duration;
        //optionally you can add ease-in and ease-out
        //lerpFactor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, lerFactor);

        // This rotates linear 
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation, targetRotation, lerpFactor);
        // OR This already rotates smoothed using a spherical interpolation
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(startRotation, targetRotation, lerpFactor);

        // yield in a Coroutine reads like
        // pause here, render this frame and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // just to be sure
    transform.rotation = targetRotation;

    isRotating = false;
}
```

Comment: `((number / seconds) * Time.deltaTime)` am I right?

Comment: yes. `number / seconds` will be your speed ... `* Time.deltaTime` converts the speed to an amount per frame

Comment: oh no, I use  `for (int i = 10 1; i > 0; i--)
                    { // rotate around here }` so It rotates only for degree =  `1/sec`

Comment: @Eloren how do you mean?

Comment: I use RotateAround in a loop for many objects. So the object rotates just a few degrees.

Comment: yes but how .. could you show the completely code for that?

Comment: `for (int i = touchedpart - 1; i > 0; i--)
                    {
                        GameObject.Find("" + i).transform.RotateAround(original, new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f), rotationdegree);
                    }`

Comment: ok where do you call this? First of all do **not** use `Find` if anyhow possible ... it is very performance intense. Then what didn't work with the method I showed you above?

Comment: I use `((rotdeg / seconds) * Time.deltaTime)`. So, gameobject1 **only** rotates during one frame, then cycle goes to the next gameobject2 and it rotates also during one frame

Comment: It locates at void Update

Comment: @Eloren please add your complete code to your question.